# How to manage Cookies in API 22

Tags: android

I'm looking on how to manage cookies and in particular Csrf token.
But the problem is that all examples I find on the net use deprecated functions in API 22 where Http connections have been widely restructured.
It's not so easy to find our way between all examples using deprecated functions.

I looked at the Android doc http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html which seems to be the one matching the HttpUrlConnection to be used in API 22 but when I write the lines:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Eclipse tells me that CookieManager cannot be instantiated. Why?
Anyway I still don't really see how Cookies will be managed.

- Is it so magic??
- Do I have to put the lines above in Activity's onCreate() to get the    cookies
  and in particular csrf token 'automatically' available in all fragments?
- Or do  have to programmatically insert the cookie in my    POST
  requests?

**EDIT**

So I modified my code like that:

first I send a GET request to get the csrfToken back.

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
//urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);


if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

    Map<String, List<String>> headers = urlConnection.getHeaderFields(); 
    for (String key: headers.keySet()) { 
        Log.w("Headers", key + " = " + Arrays.toString(headers.get(key).toArray())); 
    } 

    Cookies.saveCookies(urlConnection);

} else {
    return null;
}
```

And I verified that I get and save the csrfToken, between others.

```
Set-Cookie = [60gpBAK=R1224197954; path=/; expires=Fri, 29-May-2015 17:43:45 GMT, 60gpD=R637403390; path=/; max-age=900, csrfToken=175e1d85c1da067a2ea07b77e2f3b46b2a113620; path=/]
```

Now, my POST request:

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
Cookies.loadCookies(urlConnection);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + "UTF-8");

OutputStream output = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
output.write(params.getBytes("UTF-8"));

headers = urlConnection.getHeaderFields(); 
for (String key: headers.keySet()) { 
    Log.w("Headers", key + " = " + Arrays.toString(headers.get(key).toArray())); 
}
```

But here the Log.w() ouput is surprising: no setRequestProperty() have modified the headers 'accept-charset' is not present, 'content-type' is not the one I set, nor the cookie either ??? :

```
05-29 18:27:48.791: W/Headers(11517): null = [HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required]
05-29 18:27:48.791: W/Headers(11517): Connection = [close]
05-29 18:27:48.791: W/Headers(11517): Content-Type = [text/html; charset=iso-8859-1]
05-29 18:27:48.791: W/Headers(11517): Date = [Fri, 29 May 2015 16:27:48 GMT]
05-29 18:27:48.791: W/Headers(11517): Server = [Apache]
05-29 18:27:48.791: W/Headers(11517): Set-Cookie = [60gpD=R637403390; path=/; expires=Fri, 29-May-2015 16:46:01 GMT]
05-29 18:27:48.792: W/Headers(11517): Vary = [Accept-Encoding]
05-29 18:27:48.792: W/Headers(11517): X-Android-Received-Millis = [1432916868791]
05-29 18:27:48.792: W/Headers(11517): X-Android-Response-Source = [NETWORK 411]
05-29 18:27:48.792: W/Headers(11517): X-Android-Sent-Millis = [1432916868760]
```

What's my mistake here??

Comment: read this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180500/android-api-23-removed-packages/32377137#32377137

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem most likely, is due to wrong import. 
About question. how does this work. Well those two lines are setting default cookie manager for your whole application, and every UrlConnection call that is called after this initialization will use it.

Try to use following imports and this should work just fine.

```
 import java.net.CookieManager;
 import java.net.CookiePolicy;
```

As site note i should add, that personally i don't like setting global cookie handler and us custom one. (Everything in CookieHelper class)

```
static CookieManager myCookies;

static {
    myCookies = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
}
```

And methods to save/load to UrlConnection

```
final public static void saveCookies(HttpURLConnection connection) {
    Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = connection.getHeaderFields();
    List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get("Set-Cookie");

    if (cookiesHeader != null && myCookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
            try {
                cookie = cookie.replace("\"", "");
                myCookies.getCookieStore().add(connection.getURL().toURI(), HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

final public static void loadCookies(HttpURLConnection connection) {
    if (myCookies != null && myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0) {
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", TextUtils.join(";", myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
    }
}
```

Example use

```
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = new URL(html_url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Cookies.loadCookies(urlConnection);
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        if (urlConnection.getContentEncoding() != null && urlConnection.getContentEncoding().contains("gzip")) {
            GZIPInputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(is);
            String out = Tools.inputStreamToString(in, true).toString();
            Cookies.saveCookies(urlConnection);
            return  out; 
        } else {
            String out = Tools.inputStreamToString(is, true).toString();
            Cookies.saveCookies(urlConnection);
            return  out; 
        }
```

Comment: thanks a lot I was maybe not so far but you helped me much to correctly deal with it. I don't have the bad Csrf token error from my site but it still doesn't accept my request. I have to find why...

Comment: I often find it usefull to list headers that i receive as well as an server answer. 


    `Map<String, List<String>> headers = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
   for (String key: headers.keySet()) {
    Log.w("Headers", key + " = " + Arrays.toString(headers.get(key).toArray()));
   }`

    `Log.w("msg", urlConnection.getResponseMessage())`

Comment: I'm still fighting with it are there is something I don't really understand. If I follow your example, when I perform the first POST request, Cookies.loadCookies is supposed to return nothing right? So how this request can be accepted?

Comment: First i create new instance of cookie manager with static constructor on my utility class, thus making sure that, my own cookie manager is never null when i call load/save methods,

Comment: Then there is second part to it, what happens the first time you use load cookies there is now cookies stored yet right, but if you want, to add your own you can, 

    myCookies.getCookieStore().add(Url, HttpCookie); 

shows how you can add some cookie, if needed be you can create some simple helper method to do that for you :)

Comment: that's a nightmare! I edited my question to add what I did according to your advises. Using your debug code let me know that it seems to completely ignore the setRequestProperty() calls ! I certainly do something stupid...

Comment: Try adding this HTTP header:

    urlConnection.setRequestHeader("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");

Comment: Also before geting output stream you should also add 

urlConnection.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", sizeOfYour sent data);

Comment: the problem is currently not in my datas but really in the headers. Evrything work well if I deactivate the Csrf component and if I don't use your cookie management. But as soon as I use your cookie management, with or without Csrf component enalbed on server side, my POST requests are rejected.

Comment: when I don't take care of cookies, with the csrf component disabled on server, I get HTTP_OK. Always with csrf Component off, if I load cookies, I get a FileNotFoundException when I call getInputStream(). This may be caused by a Forbiden Exception on my server. I guess it doesn't recognize a well formed header.

Comment: @2ndGAB See this link, it solved my problem, i hope you too. https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/79/108d3aacaf4209b91b760280f82e13/frameset.htm