# Android API 23 Removed packages

Tags: android, apache, http

What is the best replacement for org.apache.http ?

since they say this in Android API Differences Report .

Removed Packages in API 23

```
org.apache.commons.logging   
org.apache.http  
org.apache.http.auth     
org.apache.http.auth.params  
org.apache.http.client   
org.apache.http.client.entity    
org.apache.http.client.methods   
org.apache.http.client.params    
org.apache.http.client.protocol  
org.apache.http.client.utils     
org.apache.http.conn.params  
org.apache.http.conn.routing     
org.apache.http.conn.util    
org.apache.http.cookie   
org.apache.http.cookie.params    
org.apache.http.entity   
org.apache.http.impl     
org.apache.http.impl.auth    
org.apache.http.impl.client  
org.apache.http.impl.conn    
org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm  
org.apache.http.impl.cookie  
org.apache.http.impl.entity  
org.apache.http.impl.io  
org.apache.http.io   
org.apache.http.message  
org.apache.http.protocol     
org.apache.http.util
```

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` is part of the sdk. It is the *natural* replacement if you don't want to use a third-party http client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Blackbelt stated, HttpURLConnection is the default replacement for the HTTPClient. If you chek [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) (at the end), you may see that thats where they will be focusing their resources.

However, is worth mentioning that some common APIs are being used, and works nicely if the focus of your app is not web browsing, but rather just using internet to fetch imgs, jsons, texts, etc.

I recommend [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html). It does look like it will be supported for a long time (based on my opinion), and is supported by google itself.

Comment: Is Volley used like a third_party

Comment: @MaherIsmaail Depends on your definition. If: `Third-party developer, a hardware or software developer independent of the primary product or platform that the consumer is using` then no, as in Google is the administrator for it. BUT, it is an "Android Open Software", so developer may increase its quality, without prior notice to you. But, if your application is selling "just internet services", then yes, as in Volley is doing that, and you cannot sell other people work as your own.

Answer (score 3):

If you are updating your project and you want continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must declare the following in your build.gradle file: ([More info here](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client))

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Watch out about your gradle version used, I'm using 2.6 at my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right DefaultHttpClient and AndroidHttpClient both network class are deprecated.

Now, only [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) is a class will get used as replacement of them. Some of the [usage](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) on Android developer site.

*"Happy Coding...!!!"*

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of seaching and reading about HttpUrlConnection & CookieManager

I find Alot of Questions about it And more Questions About sending Cookies with it

So I make a complete solution for it :

for Handle Cookies :

```
static CookieManager myCookies = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

final public static void saveCookies(HttpURLConnection connection , Context context) {
Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = connection.getHeaderFields();

List<String> cookiesHeader = null;
try {
    cookiesHeader = headerFields.get("Set-Cookie");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (cookiesHeader != null && myCookies != null) {
    for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
        try {
            cookie = cookie.replace("\"", "");
            myCookies.getCookieStore().add(connection.getURL().toURI(), HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
            String new_cookie = TextUtils.join(";", myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies());

            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("cookie", new_cookie).commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}

final public static void loadCookies(HttpURLConnection connection , Context context) {
if (myCookies != null && myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0) {
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", TextUtils.join(";", myCookies.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
}
else {
    String new_cookie = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("cookie" , "");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", new_cookie );
}
}
```

For Post Request With Json Data

```
  public String  URL_Connectin_Post ( String  endPoint , JSONObject data , Context context )
{
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(baseUrl + endPoint);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        loadCookies(urlConnection , context);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        /* optional request header */
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");

        /* optional request header  with UTF-8*/
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        /*  use this when you know data length  */
        urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.toString().getBytes("UTF-8").length);

        /*  use this when you dont  know data length  */
  //      urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(100);

        urlConnection.setUseCaches(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.connect();

        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(data.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        int responseCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            saveCookies(urlConnection , context);
            Result = convertStreamToString(in);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Result;
}
```

For Get Request

```
    public  String URL_Connectin_Get(String  endPoint , Context context)
{
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(baseUrl + endPoint);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        loadCookies(urlConnection , context);

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        int responseCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (urlConnection.getContentEncoding() != null && urlConnection.getContentEncoding().contains("gzip")) {
                GZIPInputStream inn = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                saveCookies(urlConnection , context);
            } else {
                saveCookies(urlConnection  , context);
            }
            Result = convertStreamToString(in);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Result ;
}
```